# First onDataChange too slow

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have a Fragment and in that I do various things, first I recover the current location of the device (I have a part in the Firebase Realtime Database in that the app which privately saves the location of the users, and in this Fragment I search all the near users and iterate in a list that contains all the keys (uid) of that users I found). In this iteration, I add a listener for each key to recover all the data for that user.

The first onDataChange takes a long time, between 38 and 75 seconds, even if I only retrieve one field from that user..

My code is:

```java
public void onGeoQueryReady() {
    // I have here a List of keys (uid)
    for (String key : List_keys) {
        userListener.child(key).child("token").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "onDataChange: token: "+dataSnapshot.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why does it take so long?

EDIT (10/09/2019):
Note that in the example code i recover only the "token" field of the object in database, but the problem still. In the next paragraph i added the images of database structure as links.

The first pass is for the [locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fclN7.jpg) and for each uid, i pass for look all the [user data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3aNW.jpg).

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation! I edited just a few moments ago the original message and added the database structure screenshots as links.

Comment: What you've shown here is unlikely to be the root cause. Try checking out [performance guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/monitor-performance) and [profile your db](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile). With debug logging and the profiler you should get a better picture of where the slowdown happens.

Comment: This is only in the First load, with the next it's very quick!